# Classes - require conflict in constructor

Tags: php, wordpress, scope, require

I'm coding a Wordpress plugin and I'm not sure regarding the function name conflict..

I have a file named `test_handling.php` which contains the following content :

```
function testing() { echo 'test'; }
```

I included this file in a class constructor (file named `testcls.class.php`) :

```
class TestCls {
   function __construct() {
      require_once('test_handling.php');

      testing();
   }

   function otherfunction() {
      testing();
   }

   // ...
}
```

In this case, I would like to know if the `testing()` function is only available in the `TestCls` class, or can it create conflicts if an other WP plugin has a function with the same name ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even with the same name, the functions will have different scope if defined as class method.  To make a call to a regular function you will do the following:

```
testing();
```

and the result will be:

```
'test'
```

the class method need an instance of the class or be statically called. To call the method class you will need the following formats:

```
$class->test();
```

or

```
OtherPlugin::test();
```

To sum up, the function test will be different if defined as class method. Then, you will not have conflicts.

Other way to encapsulate your function and make sure you are using the right one is with namespaces. If you use a namespace in your test_handling.php

```
<?php
namespace myname;

function testing(){echo 'test';}
?>
```

You will access the function test like this:

```
<?php 
require_once "test_handling.php";

use myname;

echo myname\testing();
```

Now you are sure about the function you are calling.

Comment: because you are not defining it as a method class. It is an standalone function defined in test_handling.php. Other way to make the function specific to your scope is using namespace.

Comment: To define it as a class method, what I have to do is placing the `static` keyword before the function definition, and use `TestCls::testing()` to calling this function, right ? Because it doesn't work neither..

Comment: You must bring it to your class. For example, otherfunction is a class method.

Comment: I can't change this method in my case (too much replacements associated).. Btw, as you said, with the namespaces, I don't have to modify the `otherfunction()` function ?

Comment: Right, I'll use namespace, thanks to you and bažmegakapa :) !

Answer (score 2):

> When a file is included, the code it contains inherits the variable
>   scope of the line on which the include occurs. Any variables available
>   at that line in the calling file will be available within the called
>   file, from that point forward. **However, all functions and classes
>   defined in the included file have the global scope**.

<sup>from [`include` in PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)</sup>

Which means that yes, you can have conflicts.

Comment: So, do you know how can I fix this problem ?

Comment: @Valentin Namespaces could be your solution, as Jose mentions.